# Unfamiliar symbol in algorithm: what does ∀ mean?

Tags: algorithm, math, symbols

I'm reading about an algorithm (it's a path-finding algorithm based on A*), and it contains a mathematical symbol I'm unfamiliar with: ∀

Here is the context:

> v(s) ≥ g(s) = min<sub>s'∈pred(s)</sub>(v(s') + c(s', s)) ∀s ≠ s<sub>start</sub>

Can someone explain the meaning of ∀?

Comment: More comments are getting flagged, and if they're not pertinent to the question, they are deleted.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

That's the "forall" (for all) symbol, as seen in [Wikipedia's table of mathematical symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_mathematical_symbols) or the [Unicode forall character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2200/index.htm) (`\u2200`, ∀).

Comment: That would make sense: "...for all s unequal to s[start]"

Comment: Thanks and +1 for the link to the table of symbols. I will use that next time I'm stumped (searching Google for ∀ turned up no records).

Comment: lol, I had never thought about googling for symbols. And apparently I didn't lose anything.

Answer (score 64):

The upside-down *A* symbol is the *universal quantifier* from [predicate logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_logic). (Also see the more complete discussion of the [first-order predicate calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic).) As others noted, it means that the stated assertions holds "for all instances" of the given variable (here, *s*). You'll soon run into its sibling, the backwards capital *E*, which is the *existential quantifier*, meaning "there exists at least one" of the given variable conforming to the related assertion.

If you're interested in logic, you might enjoy the book [*Logic and Databases: The Roots of Relational Theory*](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1430210419) by C.J. Date. There are several chapters covering these quantifiers and their logical implications. You don't have to be working with databases to benefit from this book's coverage of logic.

Comment: +1 for mentioning ∃ (U+2203 THERE EXISTS). Actually ∀ and ∃ are used in predicate calculus in general, be it first-order or higher-order. For a second-order example, in the induction axiom of Peano arithmetic you quantify over predicates and write ∀P.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I revised the reference per your suggestion.

Answer (score 16):

In math, ∀ means FOR ALL.

Unicode character (\u2200, ∀).

Comment: They call it the "Universal Qualifier".  Compare with the "Existential Qualifier".  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification

Comment: @S.Lott: nitpick s/qualifier/quantifier

Answer (score 9):

Can be read, "For all s such that s does not equal s[start]"

Answer (score 2):

yes, these are the well-known quantifiers used in math. Another example is ∃ which reads as "exists".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantification