# What is the meaning of ∃?

Tags: math, symbols

Reading a book on algorithms.  Can someone explain the meaning of the mathematical symbol ∃?

Comment: Discrete structures during the winter session? Ouch.

Comment: Belongs on MathOverflow http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: Set theory and predicate logic are 100% programming related, whomever voted to close. Although MathOverflow.net is better for pure math questions, obviously.

Comment: Given that this kind of predicated logic is a staple of CS courses, I don't see why it should be closed.

Comment: @Randolpho: Definitely. However, that has no connection to the question that was asked.

Comment: MO is not a math equivalent of SO. This question would be closed there. ("intended audience is professional mathematicians, mathematics graduate students, and advanced undergraduates." from FAQ)

Comment: I'm voting to reopen. A similar question was asked recently about ∀ (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925979/unfamiliar-symbol-in-algorithm-what-does-mean). Also it definitely does NOT belong on MathOverflow -- that's for Serious mathematical research questions; a question like this would get shut down before you could say ∀ B Ↄ....

Comment: Agreed this should be allowed. Developers should know how to write invariants, pre-conditions and post-conditions. Perfectly reasonable for someone learning the trade to ask this question.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9658/i-was-told-thered-be-no-math

Comment: @Jon Seigel: The top answer, from your link - "I would say Math questions are suitable as long as they tie into a programming concept." The explanation is required to understand an algorithm text. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @ire_and_curses: The question here does not reference any algorithm or programming concept, therefore it is a math question.

Comment: Someone who does not understand what ∃ means might not know that this is a math question. Should questions on O notation be closed because they are math questions? While it's a mathematical notation, it's usually used in analysis of algorithms. How is someone reading an algorithms text supposed to know that ∃ is any different?

Comment: Questions on O notation are always linked to algorithms, or a specific example of an algorithm. What is the context in this question? Fair point about not knowing this is a math question. However, it makes me wonder why the book the OP is reading does not contain a definition for the terminology? Any textbook I've read has a dictionary of symbols somewhere in it.

Comment: @Jon Seigel: The book almost surely does, the OP just overlooked it. Even the most advanced textbooks often have a table of symbols page somewhere just because there are inconsistencies between authors.

Comment: This is simply inane. Are we going to have a question for every mathematical symbol on Earth? Let me get it going: What is <b>א<sub>0</sub></b>?

Comment: This belongs on math.stackexchange.com, which didn't exist during all of the previous discussion.

Comment: Three months later, I'm curious why this has not been migrated to Math.SE.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It is called a [quantifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier). It means "there exists".

When used in an expression such as

```
∃x s.t. x > 0
```

It means "There exists a number `x` such that `x` is greater than 0."

Its counterpart is ∀, which means "for all". It's used like this:

```
∀x, x > 0
```

Which means "For any number `x`, it is greater than 0."

Comment: I thought that was the other way around... Huh. Learn something new every day:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%88%83

Comment: Quantifier. Predicates are something different: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)

Comment: @sdcvvc: Righto! Been a few years since my mathematical logic course. :) I've corrected the answer.

Comment: @Kieveli: Backwards "E" for "Exists", upside-down "A" for "All". That should help you, mnemonically.

Comment: Yes and ∀ you can implement complementary to ∃ since ∀x means there is no x not...eg ∀x and ∄x~ are same

Comment: We used a syntax `∀x(x>0)` and `∃x(x > 0)`

Comment: @Randolpho Both letters are rotated by 180 degrees, they just happen to have different symmetries.

Answer (score 11):

It is the "existential quantifier" as opposed to the upside-down `A` (∀) which means "universal quantifier." It should be read as "there exists" or "for some". It is a predication that means that some relation or property holds true for at least one object in the domain.

Examples:

An integer `n` is composite if `∃` integer `m` such that `m > 1` and `m < n` with `n` divisible by `m`.

An integer `n` is prime if `∀` integer `m` such that `m > 1` and `m < n` it is true that `n` is not divisible by `m`.

A function `f` is continuous on a metric space `(X, d)` if `∀x∀ε>0∃δ>0 | ∀y d(x, y) < δ => d(f(x), f(y)) < ε`

Comment: Oh no not the epsilons and deltas! Calculus 1 is flooding back to me now. I have only you to blame, Jason.

Comment: Ah, whom am I kidding? I loved Calculus 1. That's why I took Calculus 2 and Calculus 3! Thanks for that trip down memory lane.

Comment: Alternating between quantifiers produces formulas which are both hard to understand and hard to handle algorithmically. For example, the definition of continuity has the pattern ∀∃∀ (the ∀x∀y is missing in the example).

Answer (score 2):

More Info on [Predicate Logic](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Logic_for_Computer_Scientists/Predicate_Logic/Semantics)

Answer (score 2):

It is called **existential quantifier** and being followed by x, it means **there exists at least one x**

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, wikipedia has a [table of mathematical symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maths_symbols), with an explanation of the meaning(s) of each one.